# Drupal Blog Post templating

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to know how to add to a template file a blog post content rendering code so that all blogs will be displayed whenever that template is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy node.tpl.php and rename it to node--blog.tpl.php for any blog specific changes. Find more about [Drupal Template changes](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Comment: What I mean is that I have a template file let us say page--node--9.tpl.php and I want to add blog post code block to display blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your question. But if you are trying to add a block of "related posts" or something like that, you need to create a view first, and then add it to a specific region.

**Create a region from the .info file, e.g.:**

```
regions[REGION_NAME] = REGION NAME
```

**Then add this code to template.php file:**

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook)
{
  $variables['REGION_NAME'] = theme('blocks', 'REGION_NAME');
}
```

**Put this code into your node template file:**

```
<?php if ($REGION_NAME): ?>
  <div class="REGION_NAME"><?php print $REGION_NAME?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For detailed information see this post: [In DRUPAL7, how to add a region in a node.tpl.php(node--contenttype.tpl.php)?](https://drupal.org/node/1233260)

Comment: I did what you suggested. However the region did not appear in the list of region settings of the template for me to add a block. Please help.

Comment: It is working now